# how to limit instance launch by instance type in AWS using IAM service

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, policy, amazon-iam

I am using the policy to limit RunIstances only to a specific instance types and a specific region. When I run the launch wizard or simulation under a test user I am getting "implicitly denied" error.

Here is the policy:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "ec2:RunInstances",
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1::instance/*"
      ],
      "Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
          "ec2:InstanceType": [
            "t1.micro",
            "m1.small"
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "ec2:RunInstances",
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1::image/ami-*",
        "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1::subnet/*",
        "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1::network-interface/*",
        "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1::volume/*",
        "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1::key-pair/*",
        "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1::security-group/*"
      ]
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "ec2:Describe*",
        "ec2:CreateSecurityGroup",
        "ec2:DeleteSecurityGroup",
        "ec2:AuthorizeSecurityGroupIngress",
        "ec2:AuthorizeSecurityGroupEgress",
        "ec2:CreateKeyPair"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "*"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

could somebody point to the issue?

Answer (score 3):

In your resource blocks, insert an asterisk between the two ":" in the arn lines, to specify all accounts, or replace it with your account number.

```
"arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:*:instance/*"

"arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:*:image/ami-*",
"arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:*:subnet/*",
"arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:*:network-interface/*",
"arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:*:volume/*",
"arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:*:key-pair/*",
"arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:*:security-group/*"
```

Answer (score 1):

Please see the IAM policy generator tool. Your code does not look like the right syntax.

First, Allow all actions in EC2. Next, Deny specific actions in EC2.

Example to Allow all actions in EC2:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "NotAction": "ec2:*",
      "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}
```

Example to Deny creating resources in specific regions:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "DenyTheseActions",
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Action": [
        "ec2:RunInstances",
        "ec2:StartInstances"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:ec2:us-west-1",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1", 
      "Resource": "arn:aws:ec2:eu-west-1",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:ec2:sa-east-1",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:ec2:ap-northeast-1",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:ec2:ap-southeast-1",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:ec2:ap-southeast-2"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Currently the easier way to control access to AWS regions, EC2 and RDS Instances sizes and types would probably be using IAM policies with the `Condition` (Optional) policy element – *lets you specify conditions for when a policy is in effect*.

We'll setup an **AWS IAM Policy** using a `Condition` statement, which will allow full AWS **EC2** and **RDS** services, strictly for the [3 more cost effective](https://www.concurrencylabs.com/blog/choose-your-aws-region-wisely/) -> [AWS regions](https://infrastructure.aws/) which are:

- us-east-1 (North Virginia, USA)
- us-east-2 (Ohio, USA)
- us-west-2 (Oregon, USA)

All other regions will not be allowed, this policy also sets up a conditional access control for starting both **EC2** and **RDS instances**. Instead of specifying all of the possible [type/class](http://www.ec2instances.info) instances to run, we use `Deny` effect in the statement, which allows for a short and simple policy limiting by instances sizes (`micro`, `small`, `medium` and `large`). This has the further effect of preventing any other policies from overriding the block.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "MultiServiceFullAccessCustom",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:*",
                "rds:*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "*"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "aws:RequestedRegion": [
                        "us-east-1",
                        "us-east-2",
                        "us-west-2"
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Sid": "Ec2RunInstanceCustomSize",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Action": "ec2:RunInstances",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:instance/*"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "ForAnyValue:StringNotLike": {
                    "ec2:InstanceType": [
                        "*.nano",
                        "*.micro",
                        "*.small",
                        "*.medium",
                        "*.large"
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Sid": "RdsFullAccessCustomSize",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Action": [
                "rds:CreateDBInstance",
                "rds:CreateDBCluster"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:rds:*:*:db:*"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "ForAnyValue:StringNotLike": {
                    "rds:DatabaseClass": [
                        "*.micro",
                        "*.small",
                        "*.medium",
                        "*.large"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

#### What does this policy not protect us from?

- This does not impose limits on the size of instances deployed though other services - most importantly, through an auto-scaling group or EKS.
- We are not limiting in any way the total number of instances spun up by a given user. The normal limits help here, but there isn't a way to determine how many instances are currently running through just policy.
- We're not capping costs, just adding some protections. If you want to set alerts for cost overruns or spikes, you need to look into the Billing controls.

  - [terraform-aws-cost-billing-alarm](https://registry.terraform.io/modules/binbashar/cost-billing-alarm/aws/0.0.2)
  - [terraform-aws-cost-budget](https://registry.terraform.io/modules/binbashar/cost-budget/aws/0.0.6)
  - [terraform-aws-lambda-nuke](https://registry.terraform.io/modules/diodonfrost/lambda-nuke/aws/2.1.2)
  - [terraform-aws-lambda-scheduler-stop-start](https://registry.terraform.io/modules/diodonfrost/lambda-scheduler-stop-start/aws/2.1.5)
- We do not require any Multi Factor Authentication (MFA) for the role switch. The assumption is that users logging in are already using some form of second factor for authentication. This is mostly due to the increased complexity around using the CLI with MFA, and the fact that the role change is only to allow an override, not to enable an elevation to another security domain. You might want to add the feature; it is not difficult to add, and can bring reasonable protections.
- We are only looking at instance startup, but you may consider who can shutdown or terminate instances, as that may result in downtime or data loss.

#### Reference links

- https://blog.vizuri.com/limiting-allowed-aws-instance-type-with-iam-policy
- https://blyx.com/2016/03/24/how-to-restrict-by-regions-and-instance-types-in-aws-with-iam/
- https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/easier-way-to-control-access-to-aws-regions-using-iam-policies/
- https://medium.com/faun/100-days-of-devops-day-10-restricting-user-to-launch-only-t2-instance-509aaaec5aa2
- https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/back-to-school-understanding-the-iam-policy-grammar/